# AngularUI Boostrap typeahead doesn't select when item is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am new to Angular and having issues with the AngularUI bootstrap toolkit where clicking on an item in the dropdown, doesn't fill the  textbox with the full value. The dropdown box disappears when clicked and only the characters that were typed are left in.

Here is the code (start typing "spy" into the textbox)

http://plnkr.co/edit/WYLn0c6HvuOLl1pJBCxa?p=preview

```
<body>
  <div data-ng-controller="AssetCtrl">
    <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="asset.ticker as typeaheadLabel(asset) for asset in assets | filter:{ticker:$viewValue}" class="form-control">

  </div>



  <script>
    var ConsoleApp = angular.module('ConsoleApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    function AssetCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.assets = [{
        "assetClass": "stock",
        "ticker": "spy",
        "description": "S&P"
      }];

      $scope.typeaheadLabel = function(item) {
        return item.ticker.toUpperCase() + ' (' + item.assetClass + ') - ' + item.description;
      };
    }

    ConsoleApp.controller('AssetCtrl', AssetCtrl);
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the issue lies in the `typeaheadLabel` function which gets evaluated while calculating the model value and often the `item` comes as null. You could add some defensive null checks on the label function so that value evaluation doesn't get broken, because this is what typeahead actually matches the value of the model as :-

*Snippet From TypeAhead*

```
return {
        itemName:match[3],
        source:$parse(match[4]),
        viewMapper:$parse(match[2] || match[1]), //<-- here if the function evaluation is undefined which is in your case it will take the value of ticker propery as modelValue
        modelMapper:$parse(match[1])
      };
```

WorkAround1:-

```
  $scope.typeaheadLabel = function(item) {
    if(!item || !item.ticker) return;
    return item.ticker.toUpperCase() + ' (' + item.assetClass + ') - ' + item.description;
  };
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IPVAjyWRbtJlCghrNQvL?p=preview)**

Another way i would suggest is to add a displayName property in the viewModel itself. Ex:-

WorkAround 2:

```
   $scope.assets = [{
        "assetClass": "stock",
        "ticker": "spy",
        "description": "S&P"
      },{
        "assetClass": "stock",
        "ticker": "asd",
        "description": "A&D"
      }].map(typeaheadLabel);


      function typeaheadLabel(item) {
        item.displayName = item.ticker.toUpperCase() + ' (' + item.assetClass + ') - ' + item.description;
        return item;
      };
```

and specify `displayName` as alias `asset.ticker as asset.displayName for asset in assets`

**[Plnkr2](http://plnkr.co/edit/bE6y1BKwQza6wazRIPbC?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful! Your second solution (displayName) only works with Angular 1.2 and not the current 1.3.x beta. I'm not sure why, but once I changed that and incorporated your solution, everything worked as Plnkr showed.